# How to Group date Column (to date ,month and year) in Excel Pivot Table using Java Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am developing an application using Java apache POI that integrate with Excel to create Pivot table for some data in xslx file extension using XSSFWorkbook

and i have date column that contain date values like this "1/8/2016"

[image]

and i want to grouping this column in this pivot table into day , months and years like that using java Apache poi

[image]

so any help  ?